# How can I generalize a lot of categorical variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, feature-engineering

I have the following df in R:

```
ID      GENDER        COUNTRY
1         M             US
2         M             UK
3         F             JPN
4         F             NED
```

There are over 50 different countries, I want to summarize this info as follows. If the person is from the top 10 most popular countries (popular countries are the countries with the most records), COUNTRY_POPULAR will be 1, else 0. Ex US and UK happened to be in the top 10 frequent in this df and JPN and NED were not:

```
ID      GENDER        COUNTRY         COUNTRY_POPULAR 
1         M             US                   1
2         M             UK                   1
3         F             JPN                  0
4         F             NED                  0
```

Comment: top10 most popular countries in your table? Or by some other definition

Comment: I believe your question is unclear. What is "generalize"? How/Where are popular countries defined?  Please be a bit more clear.

Comment: I edited the question. Yes, assuming US and UK are among the top 10 most occured country, the column is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `table` to count the occurrence of each `country`, `sort` them select the top 10 countries using `tail` and assign 1/0 values based on their presence/absence.

```
df$COUNTRY_POPULAR <- +(df$COUNTRY %in% names(tail(sort(table(df$COUNTRY)), 10)))
```

The `+` ahead converts the logical values `TRUE`/`FALSE` to 1/0 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do it using `dplyr`, this is another option which allows you to take care of countries which might be tied in their ranking:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Get the top 10 countries (count allows you to untie countries which might have the same position, so an addition to the answer).
top_10 <-
  df %>%
  count(COUNTRY, sort = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  pull(COUNTRY)


# If the country is in the top 10, assign a 1 otherwise a 0.
df %>%
  mutate(COUNTRY_POPULAR = if_else(COUNTRY %in% top_10, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'popular' is appearing the most in the database, one way is to create an interim column with the rank:

Say your data.frame is called `df`:

```
# get the count of how many times a country is mentioned 
df <- plyr::ddply(df, .(COUNTRY), mutate, rank = n())

# create the popular column
df$COUNTRY_POPULAR <- ifelse(df$rank <= 10, 1, 0)
```

Then you can remove the rank column.

**EDIT:**

No need to `summarise` then `merge`, you can just `mutate` instead.

Comment: load the `plyr` and `dplyr` libraries first